# Double checking daylight savings rules on PostgreSQL server are up to date?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, dst

We run PostgreSQL, interfacing with source systems that store timestamps without time zones, fixed to 'America/Los_Angeles'. We convert those to UTC and store them with the UTC time zone (of course).

In the conversion, there is a daylight savings rule lookup. I want to double check to make sure that the rules are up to date. (The start and end dates move every year, of course.)

Where is this stored? How does this get updated?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL apparently uses the zoneinfo database. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database

So as long as that's kept up to date, then everything is fine.